# How to commit the folderA and fileB (in folderA) separately?

Tags: git, commit

I have a folder that contains some files,if I add one additional file in this folder ,and right now I would like to commit,It's it possible to do commit them separately ? Something like :

1. commit to this folder : "Add a new file"
2. commit to the additional file : "new algorithm"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply:

1. Add only file that you want to commit `git add myfile.ext`
2. Commit changes `git commit -m "Add a new file"`
3. Add rest `git add *`
4. Commit new changes `git commit -m "new algorithm"`

Comment: not working... my case is if I create a folder called test2  and cd to test2 then create a file test1.txt And I would like to commit test1.txt and test2 separately
I follow your step ,and to step 4 give me the message : Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: Strange, git-commit shouldn't check anything with remote repositories